# Optimización de indices

Tags: mysql, sql, optimización, rendimiento, indices

He estado haciendo algunas pruebas de performace sobre una tabla (*appointments*) usando el gestor MySQL que figura como la siguiente:

| id | start_date | end_date | doctor_id  |

- **Id**: int Primary key
- **start_date**: datetime
- **end_date**: datetime
- **doctor_id**: int FK

Tengo un indice en las columnas start_date y end_date (En ese orden)

He cargado previamente 3.5 Millones de registros a la tabla.

[Caso 1]
El primer query que realice fue el siguiente:
[image]
Dando como resultado 0.0666 segundos.
Y ejecutando el comando explain al query me muestra lo siguiente:
[image]
Donde efectivamente usa el index.

[Caso 2]
En el siguiente caso, agrego un filtro extra a la columna del doctor:

[image]

Aumentando significativamente el tiempo de respuesta.
Y con explain muestra lo siguiente:
[image]

[Caso 3]
Quité el filtro del doctor, pero ahora le añadí la función DATE a la columna startDate para hacer la consulta.
[image]
Y el explain

[image]

Las preguntas son las siguientes:

1. En el caso 2, ¿Sería viable agregar un indice a las columnas doctor_id y start_date para optimizar las consultas?
2. ¿Por qué en el caso 3 es mas rápido inclusive que el caso 1, incluso si el caso 3 esta haciendo una búsqueda de tipo FULL y sin indices? (Reinicie el contenedor para eliminar la cache de la BD)
3. ¿Los indicies en el caso 2 funcionaran igualmente con funciones, o bajo que parametros, el optimizador no puede hacer uso de ellos?

Nota: Los tests se realizaron en un contenedor de docker, MySQL8, con un maximo de 8 GB de memoria sobre una maquina con procesador i7.

Comment: Cuando usas funciones sobre los valores de los campos, el indexado deja de ser útil porque igual hay que transformar TOOOOODOS los valores para saber cuáles cumplen la condición. No te sirve revisar el between sin el cast a date? Lo del índice sobre doctor_id, realmente depende de la selectividad del índice; cuántos valores diferentes puede tener? Si hay 3 id, igual ese filtro no va a reducir mucho el resultset...

Comment: Si, pero para los casos que planteo es importante mencionarla

Comment: en el caso 3, cambiaste el where.. no vale la prueba...

Comment: filtered, estaba explicado en [database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164251/what-is-the-meaning-of-filtered-in-mysql-explain)

Comment: Tienes razón, olvidé quitar la función, sin embargo aun es confuso porque resulta mas rapida

Comment: Si no nos decis como aplicaste el range, no podemos ayudarte con esa parte...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta, conlleva mil preguntas mas... Ojo con eso... hay cosas que podes probar vos...

Comment: Evita adjuntar imágenes, no todos pueden verlas. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que sea necesario para poder comprender mejor tu problema.